# displaying images in command window

Tags: image, window, octave

I would like to do a zoom lesson on some aspects of octave. It would be very convenient if I can have it display the figures and images in the command window. Is there a way to do that?
Thanks

Comment: By "command window" you mean using Octave in GUI mode? Do you necessarily want them to appear in the "command window", or do you simply want to only share a single window and would like the figures to appear as part of the interface instead of as a separate window? What is your exact requirement. No octave does not have an ipython-like mode. If you really *really* want that you could demonstrate octave using the octave-online website which has that feature. https://octave-online.net/

Answer (score 1):

An Octave Jupyter Notebook is made for this kind of application.
You will find other threads dealing with this topic.
However, you should check that such a notebook can be shared through a zoom session. I have never tried.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Octave can show plots in the command Window with the help of Gnuplot's `dumb` terminal:

```
close all
graphics_toolkit gnuplot
setenv GNUTERM dumb
plot (1:10)
```

... but that is quite ugly :-).

So I agree with previous answers that using a Jupyter notebook together with the [octave_kernel](https://github.com/Calysto/octave_kernel) would probably be the best choice.